# Is it possible to compile remotely flutter code for ios in Windows/Linux

Tags: flutter, dart

I am comparing Xamarin and Flutter. Xamarin can compile the code for ios remotely according to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/). is this possible for Flutter? I searched the Flutter FAQ page but I can not find an answer.

Comment: I guess technically it is possible as with Xamarin, but not wired up (not supported by tools yet)